# creating datasheet view - but standard view is displayed by default

Tags: datasheet

```
SPView AllItems = spList.Views["myview"] ;
AllItems.Formats = "<Format Name=\"Modified\"><FormatDef Type=\"ColWidth\" Value=\"534\" /></Format>";      
AllItems.Update();
```

Why isn't this working? No error is given; the view is there. But the datasheet view does not automatically appears when I click on the list.

Answer (score 3):

I guess I dont need the format part. All I had to do make viewtype to grid. I dont even have to format each field (like I posted in the original email).

```
oViewCollection.Add(strViewName, viewFields, strQuery, 100, true, true, SPViewCollection.SPViewType.Grid,false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the DefaultView property of the list.

```
// set web = the SPWeb that your list is in
SPList list = web.Lists["My List"];
list.Views["myview"].DefaultView = true;
list.Update();
```

Comment: That did not work. The view displays as standard view instead of intended datasheet view.